# Facebook: change logout url

Tags: php, facebook, url, logout

My web is built dynamically. I have page1.php, page2.php .. etc .but they are called by something like:  index.php?page=page1

When I click the logout button it reloads page1.php instead of index.php?page=page1

How do I have to change the code for the correct reload to happen, what do I have to edit?

Here's the code I'm using:

I have the logout button in this way:

```
<a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>"><img border=0 src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z2Y31/hash/cxrz4k7j.gif"></a>
```

Where:

```
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
```

I'm including facebook.php and here's getLogoutUrl();:

```
public function getLogoutUrl($params=array()) {   
    return $this->getUrl(
      'www',
      'logout.php',
      array_merge(array(
        'next'         => $this->getCurrentUrl(),
        'access_token' => $this->getAccessToken(),
      ), $params)
    );
  }
```

And getCurrentUrl():

```
 protected function getCurrentUrl() {
    $protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'
      ? 'https://'
      : 'http://';
    $currentUrl = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $parts = parse_url($currentUrl);

    // drop known fb params
    $query = '';
    if (!empty($parts['query'])) {
      $params = array();
      parse_str($parts['query'], $params);
      foreach(self::$DROP_QUERY_PARAMS as $key) {
        unset($params[$key]);
      }
      if (!empty($params)) {
        $query = '?' . http_build_query($params, null, '&');
      }
    }

    // use port if non default
    $port =
      isset($parts['port']) &&
      (($protocol === 'http://' && $parts['port'] !== 80) ||
       ($protocol === 'https://' && $parts['port'] !== 443))
      ? ':' . $parts['port'] : '';

    // rebuild
    return $protocol . $parts['host'] . $port . $parts['path'] . $query;
  }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling

```
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
```

you can tell him where do you want him to return the user once he loges out:

```
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(
    array(
        'next' => 'http://mydomain.com/index.php?page=page1'
    )
);
```